# Attach a dataframe with a column that have a different number of rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to bind a data frame with the last column of another dataframe, but they have a different number of rows. I want to fill with NA this gap, but by group. Example:

**I have `df` and `df_B`:**

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

date <- seq(from = as_date("2019-11-01"), to = as_date("2020-10-01"), by = "month")
            
country <- c(rep("Brazil",6), rep("UK", 6))

A <- 1:12

df <- data.frame(date, country, A)
```

```
> view(df)

         date country  A
1  2019-11-01  Brazil  1
2  2019-12-01  Brazil  2
3  2020-01-01  Brazil  3
4  2020-02-01  Brazil  4
5  2020-03-01  Brazil  5
6  2020-04-01  Brazil  6
7  2020-05-01      UK  7
8  2020-06-01      UK  8
9  2020-07-01      UK  9
10 2020-08-01      UK 10
11 2020-09-01      UK 11
12 2020-10-01      UK 12
```

```
date <- c(seq(from = as_date("2020-01-01"), to = as_date("2020-04-01"), by = "month"),
           seq(from = as_date("2020-07-01"), to = as_date("2020-10-01"), by = "month"))
            
country <- c(rep("Brazil",4), rep("UK", 4))

B <- 5:12

df_B <- data.frame(date, country, B)
```

```
> view(df_B)

        date  country B
1 2020-01-01  Brazil  5
2 2020-02-01  Brazil  6
3 2020-03-01  Brazil  7
4 2020-04-01  Brazil  8
5 2020-07-01      UK  9
6 2020-08-01      UK 10
7 2020-09-01      UK 11
8 2020-10-01      UK 12
```

**What I want is the following result**:

```
         date country  A  B
1  2019-11-01  Brazil  1  NA
2  2019-12-01  Brazil  2  NA
3  2020-01-01  Brazil  3  5
4  2020-02-01  Brazil  4  6
5  2020-03-01  Brazil  5  7
6  2020-04-01  Brazil  6  8
7  2020-05-01      UK  7  NA
8  2020-06-01      UK  8  NA
9  2020-07-01      UK  9  9
10 2020-08-01      UK 10  10
11 2020-09-01      UK 11  11
12 2020-10-01      UK 12  12
```

I appreciate it if someone can help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a merge/join operation. More explanation on these concepts can be found [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272) and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/3358272.

Using `dplyr`,

```r
library(dplyr)
left_join(df, df_B, by=c("date", "country"))
#          date country  A  B
# 1  2019-11-01  Brazil  1 NA
# 2  2019-12-01  Brazil  2 NA
# 3  2020-01-01  Brazil  3  5
# 4  2020-02-01  Brazil  4  6
# 5  2020-03-01  Brazil  5  7
# 6  2020-04-01  Brazil  6  8
# 7  2020-05-01      UK  7 NA
# 8  2020-06-01      UK  8 NA
# 9  2020-07-01      UK  9  9
# 10 2020-08-01      UK 10 10
# 11 2020-09-01      UK 11 11
# 12 2020-10-01      UK 12 12
```

As a word of "caution", or least a simple warning: joining with numeric-like columns is fine as long as they are effectively discrete, such as `integer`, or `POSIXct`/`Date` that are close-enough to be integers. If you note that `dput(df$date)` shows integer-like numbers, but they are really `numeric` not `integer`s, we are now in the realm of "R doing what one would expect to happen.

However, dates can (if mathematically calculated) be partial-days, as in

```r
Sys.Date() + c(0, 0.5)
# [1] "2020-12-14" "2020-12-14"
dput(Sys.Date() + c(0, 0.5))
# structure(c(18610, 18610.5), class = "Date")
```

we realize that what *looks* discrete on the surface may not be. Going one step further, the concept of "equality" with continuous (not discrete) numbers is a hit-or-miss thing, in R and many/most other programming languages. Computers have limitations when it comes to floating-point numbers (aka `double`, `numeric`, `float`). This is a fundamental limitation of computers in general, in how they deal with non-integer numbers. There are some add-on libraries or packages that are much better at arbitrary-precision math, but I believe most main-stream languages (this is relative/subjective, I admit) do not use these by default. Refs: [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518), [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004), and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

With this in mind, if in the future you do a search using `Date` objects and something is not joined correctly, take a look at whether your numbers are truly discrete or if you have some floating-point dates in there.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the explation

Comment: I'm getting this error: "`x` and `y` must share the same src, set `copy` = TRUE (may be slow)". I don't know if its normal

Comment: That can happen if one (or neither) of them are `data.frame`. Are you using database connections and `dbplyr`?